# Micropython: How to debounce the Pyboard USR switch?

Tags: debouncing, micropython

I currently have this [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/) code running on a [Pyboard v1.1](https://store.micropython.org/#/products/PYBv1_1):

```
import pyb

def toggle_led():
    pyb.LED(3).toggle()

sw = pyb.Switch()
sw.callback(toggle_led)
```

However, this setup is susceptible to [contact bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce).

I tried adding up to `pyb.delay(500)` to no avail.

Is there an elegant way to remedy `USR` switch bounce on the Pyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. I got my inspiration from a procedure described in a post on the [MicroPython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=1938#p10931).

```
import pyb

def toggle_led():
    pyb.disable_irq()
    pyb.delay(100)
    if sw.value(): pyb.LED(3).toggle()
    pyb.enable_irq()

sw = pyb.Switch()
sw.callback(toggle_led)
```

#### Better: uasyncio

There is a much better way without a need for interrupts.
Here is a link to the [**buttons example**](https://github.com/peterhinch/micropython-async/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#71-why-scheduling) in Peter Hinch's excellent uasyncio tutorial.

Comment: You should probably use [micropython.schedule](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/micropython.html#micropython.schedule) to have the `LED.toggle` method called outside of the IRQ handler. Because you can't use bound methods directly with `schedule` and schedule always passes its second arg to the scheduled function, you have to make a little wrapper outside of your interrupt function (e.g. `led_toggle = lambda led: led.toggle()`  and then schedule that: `micropython.schedule(led_toggle, led)`.

Comment: @ChrisArndt I read the [micropython.schedule](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/library/micropython.html#micropython.schedule) documentation, but it still remains pretty etheric to me; more so because above code does what it needs to do. Perhaps you should write a full answer with a working code example. Cheers.

Comment: @ChrisArndt Someone posted a solution involving `micropython.schedule` [over here](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1938&p=23453#p23472).

Comment: That was me! ;)